# How to create Datasets Like MNIST in Pytorch?

Tags: dataset, pytorch

I have looked Pytorch source code of MNIST dataset but it seems to read numpy array directly from binaries.
How can I just create train_data and train_labels like it? I have already prepared images and txt with labels.

I have learned how to read image and label and write get_item and len, what really confused me is how to make **train_data** and **train_labels**, which is torch.Tensor. I tried to arrange them into python lists and convert to torch.Tensor but failed:

```
for index in range(0,len(self.files)):
  fn, label = self.files[index]
  img = self.loader(fn)
  if self.transform is not None:
    img = self.transform(img)
  train_data.append(img)
self.train_data = torch.tensor(train_data)
```

ValueError: only one element tensors can be converted to Python scalars

Comment: on https://github.com/rajsingh8220/PyTorch-Basics , look at loading images and data. and read three major operations when we load data on https://github.com/rajsingh8220/PyTorch-Basics/blob/master/PyTorch9%20-%20Loading%20Image%20Data.ipynb (Read images, transform and load - three operations)

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to go. First, the manual. [Torchvision.datasets](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/torchvision/datasets.html) states the following:

> datasets are subclasses of torch.utils.data.Dataset i.e, they have `__getitem__` and `__len__` methods implemented. Hence, they can all be passed to a torch.utils.data.DataLoader which can load multiple samples parallelly using torch.multiprocessing workers.

So you can just implement your own class which scans for all the images and labels, keeps a list of their paths (so that you don't have to keep them in RAM) and has the `__getitem__` method which given index `i` reads the i-th file, its label and returns them. This minimal interface is enough to work with the parallel [dataloader](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/data.html#torch.utils.data.DataLoader) in [torch.utils.data](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/data.html).

Secondly, if your data directory can be rearranged into either structure, you can use [DatasetFolder](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/torchvision/datasets.html#torchvision.datasets.DatasetFolder) and [ImageFolder](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/torchvision/datasets.html#torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder) pre-built loaders. This will save you some coding and automatically provide support for data augumentation routines from [torchvision.transforms](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/torchvision/transforms.html).